# why is my CSS animation lagging on mobile?

Tags: css, animation, filter, hover, dropshadow

I just created this animation on my website. it's basically supposed to make the logo glow.

[image] I tried it on a real mobile device and it's super laggy and slow. Here's the css responsible for the animation, it's super simple:

```css
.portfolio_item {
  border-radius: 6px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.portfolio_item img {
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 1px #eee) grayscale(100%);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.portfolio_item:hover img {
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 200px #eee) grayscale(0%);
}
```

Here's a link to the website so you can try it yourself
http://ayadighaith.com/

Comment: did you try `transition: filter 0.3s ease`?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://www.afasterweb.com/2016/01/31/css-filters-and-mobile-performance/

Comment: It's transition: all 0.3s ease, all means I don't have to specifically name the property that's going to change right?

Comment: That is correct, but that may add to poor performance. You should only give the rules, that will be animated. You can also try to set `will-change: filter;`: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/will-change´

Comment: Thank you. Will try these out